# Cannot find time.h (timezone, daylight, tzname) in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am unable to find `time.h` (specifically the identifiers `timezone`, `daylight` and `tzname`) in Visual Studio 2015 (14.0). The include is present in Visual Studio 2013 (under `VC/includes`) and is also found if I compile with `VS2015` and `PlatformToolset=v120`.

Is my installation partial? Why there's no `time.h`, and even a recursive grep under `VS2015/VC` I can't seem to find those identifiers?

Comment: which version of VS 2015 are you using ? Profession ? Enterprise ?

Comment: @AjitMedhekar professional

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The headers, sources, and libraries are now distributed as part of a separate 
**Universal CRT SDK**. This SDK is included with Visual Studio, it is installed by 
default to **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10"** instead of "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC".

[Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/) is the reference.

Comment: That's very interesting and indeed seems to be the case, thanks.

Comment: I rechecked my VS2015 configuration. It appears that I have `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt` in my configuration (`Property pages -> Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories -> General -> Include Directories`). It's apparently brought in as inherited properties under $VC_IncludePath or $WindowsSDK_IncludePath... so at this point I don't really know what's the problem...

Answer (score 2):

I came here because my C program, originally compiled with GCC, wouldn't compile under Visual Studio 2015. Just like Stefano Borini, I got error messages about the keyword `timezone` offered by **time.h**. I found the MSVC version of **time.h** in the location mentioned by Ajit Medhekar but that was already being properly included.

The actual reason for the compilation error is that Microsoft offers keyword `_timezone` with a leading underscore. Perhaps somewhere among the million compilation switches this behavior can be made GCC-compatible, but I've just added this underscore to my source code.